# what is use of Koustomize.yaml?

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

Is it the same / similar to requirement.txt in Python or package.json in the Node.js world?

Just trying to draw a parallel.

(early help is appreciated - preparing for an interview)

Answer (score 2):

It’s the configuration file for Kustomize, listing which files to pull into the current overlay tree and some global parameters, and things like setting up generators.